# How can I filter tracking IDs in SQL based on single status only?

Tags: sql, database, bigdata

I have a massive database with over 5 million rows.
The rows have Duplicate tracking ids because they have multiple products in each of the Tracking ids with different statuses.

So for example, Tracking1 has two units, one is sellable, the other is destroy.

I would like to filter out Tracking Ids with multiple statuses and only leave the ones with one status but since the tracking ID repeats based on the status I can't use a Where clause to filter out Destroy for example as it would remove one row Tracking6 but leave the other one. If that makes sense.

The database looks like this but with 5 million rows:

[image]

Can't seem to get a code working at the moment as each Where clause removed the rows that I would like to see.

Comment: Hi - please don't link to images, provide all relevant information as editable text. Can you update your question with enough sample data to illustrate the issue, show the result you want to achieve (based on on your sample data) and the SQL you've managed to write so far? Thanks

Comment: Can you tag the DBMS you are using?

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Answer (score 0):

To exclude rows with duplicate IDs, your query can take the following form:

```
SELECT *
  FROM TRACK_TABLE
 WHERE TRACKINGID NOT IN ( SELECT GRP.TRACKINGID
                             FROM (   SELECT TRACKINGID, STATUS
                                        FROM TRACK_TABLE
                                    GROUP BY TRACKINGID, STATUS ) GRP
                           GROUP BY GRP.TRACKINGID
                             HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 )
```

The sub-select gets a list of all the tracking ids that have more than one row in the GRP sub-select. The GRP sub-select will combine all similar tracking id and status combinations into a single row. That way, only those with different status will appear twice. The outer select returns any thing in the table with a tracking id that is *not* in that list.

Comment: But I don't want to remove all the duplicates. 
Just the ones with multiple statuses. 
So for example:
Tracking1 has 1 sellable unit and 1 destroy unit so I want it to be excluded.
But Tracking2 has 3 sellable units so I want it to be included.

Comment: @Kael_1993 Ah, sorry about that. I've updated my answer. May not be the most elegant way, but if your db supports subselects in the `FROM` clause, the updated answer should do what you want.